# How to add char type SqlParameter in SQL LIKE % %?

Tags: c#, t-sql, ado.net

Can't get this working, how to add a parameter in SQL LIKE % %  when its type is char?

```
SQL.Append("(Code LIKE @Code)");
var sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@Code",
                      System.Data.SqlDbType.Char, 
                      10,
                      System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
                      true, 
                      0, 
                      0, 
                      "Code", 
                      System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, 
                      "'%300%'");
```

Comment: Do you have any error message?

Comment: No error message, the query just doesn't return anything with a parameter. But with dynamic SQL it works (Code LIKE '%300%')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your code, the first [Soner pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29751114/80274), you need to remove the single quotes from your string. The second is the fact that you are using `System.Data.SqlDbType.Char` as the datatype and passed in a size of 10 to the constructor. This will pad out 10 spaces at the end of your string, effectively turning your string in to `"'%300%'   "`

Use `SqlDbType.VarChar` instead. Also you don't need all those parameters in the constructor, just fill in the 3 you need then use the `.Value` property of the parameter you created.

```
SQL.Append("(Code LIKE @Code)");
var sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@Code", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
sqlParameter.Value = "%300%";
```

Also, another trick that may be useful to you. If you want to always put the % on both sides but don't want the user to have to provide them you can put them in your query and still use parameters.

```
string code = "300";

SQL.Append("(Code LIKE '%' + @Code + '%')");
var sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@Code", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
sqlParameter.Value = code;
```

Comment: Big thanks! With the SqlDbType.VarChar it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use your parameter value without single quotes. I think they make your value part as a [string literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) instead of parameter.

```
"%300%"
```

Comment: @Soner I think the problem also comes from the fact that he is using `SqlDbType.Char` and it is padding his string with spaces which the like is searching for.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Exactly, that was my second thought. If you looking for `300` in your column, sounds like you should not choose `Char` type at all.